# Can confluence display branch, commit hash, and date from Bitbucket/Jenkins servers?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, confluence, documentation-generation

I have several projects being built and auto deployed by Jenkins, which is building from code stored in a BitBucket repository. I would like to have a central Confluence page that other teams can access which will display what the latest build for each project was (Current branch, date, git hash, etc).

I hope there is a plugin that would allow it from Confluence to Jenkins, but I have been unable to find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you have to do then.

- Integrate Confluence and BitBucket by an application link (you have to be an administrator for both systems then).
- Install a plugin into Confluence, that allows to see BitBucket content or metadata then. You may find a list of plugins [here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=confluence&query=bitbucket). (I have no experience with any of the plugins ...)
- Look at the [plugins for Jenkins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?product=confluence&query=jenkins), perhaps there is something useful for you as well.

I have found most of the stuff myself on [the Atlassian Community portal](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-integrate-confluence-for-bitbucket/qaq-p/35638?tempId=eyJvaWRjX2NvbnNlbnRfbGFuZ3VhZ2VfdmVyc2lvbiI6IjEuMCIsIm9pZGNfY29uc2VudF9ncmFudGVkX2F0IjoxNTcyMjc4NDU1MTgwfQ%3D%3D).